# Изменение GUID элемента в конфигурации 1С

Tags: 1с

Я имею две конфигурации 1С, и в одной из них есть элемент, к примеру, отчет. Мне нужно перенести этот элемент в другую конфигурацию, но при этом GUID элемента будет оставаться таким же, есть ли возможность полностью изменить его, что бы не было возможности определить, что этот элемент был перенесен из другой конфигурации? И как это сделать?
Заранее большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если это отчёт, то легче всего

1. Создать новый отчет
2. Сохранить его
3. Сравнением\объединением накинуть на него функционал нужного отчета.